# Finite Difference Approach for the 1D Conservative Advection Equation with Spacially Varying Velocity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, computational-mathematics

I am attempting to numerically solve the following conservative advection equation in 1D, using a finite difference method.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(v(x,t)u(x,t)\right) = 0 \hspace{1cm}$ (1)

where $u(x,t)$ is the quantity I am interested in and $v(x,t)$ is the velocity with which it is advected. I have another equation governing the evolution of $v$, so it can be assumed that at each time-step I know the value of $v$ on the whole domain, and can use this information to calculate $u$ at the next time-step. I have looked into a number of schemes but none of them seem suitable. A lot of the books and articles I have looked at deal with equations of the form:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u(x,t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f\left(u(x,t)\right) = 0$

but they all seem to assume that the function $f$ can be differentiated to rewrite the equation as:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u(x,t) + f'(u)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,t) = 0$

However, in the case of equation (1), it does not seem clear how to do this. Writing $f(u) = vu$, one could naively suppose that $f'(u)=v(x,t)$ but implicit differentiation in (1) gives:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t) + v(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,t) + u(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(x,t) = 0$

in which a stray $u(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(x,t)$ term appears. I have considered rewriting equation (1) as:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t) + v(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,t) = -u(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(x,t)$

and considering the right hand side as a source term, but I'm not entirely sure where to go with this. My method needs to be conservative and stable. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your equation has both u and v. Do you have any information about v?

Comment: Yes, I have another equation governing the evolution of $v$, so it can be assumed that at each time-step I know the value of $v$ on the whole domain, and can use this information to calculate $u$ at the next time-step.

Comment: I think you need not move the derivative of v to the right hand side. I assume you can compute the derivative of v w.r.t x explicitly. You can try writing the upwind scheme, for example. At particular points of x, such that x_n compute the derivative of v at this point explicitly. Then the whole equation is in u_n and u_n-1.

Comment: Would this scheme be conservative? Would there be a simple condition (some form of CFL) for such an upwind scheme to be stable? Also, would my "upwind" direction depend on the sign of $v$ at each point in space?

Comment: Your scheme will be dependent on the value of v at each time and position. As for CFL condition, it may not assume a simple form as there is a varying v. For stability, you can try writing a code to try see whether the scheme is stable. Often, we use fft analysis to see whether a scheme is stable, but that applies to simple schemes. I don't think you can easily bound v even if you do by the traditional energy method. I am not sure regarding conservative issue. Apologies